# Read data from a website with Matlab

Tags: matlab, web-scraping, datareader

Can someone show me how to read data from this website: http://www.amlbook.com/data/zip/features.train

I used to copy+paste to form a array in my Matlab editor, but this time it seems the data amount is huge...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
block = URLREAD('http://www.amlbook.com/data/zip/features.train');
readData = textscan(block,'%f%f%f','delimiter', char(9));
train1 = readData{1};
train2 = readData{2};
train3 = readData{3};
clear readData
```

Three 7291*1 double arrays are imported, representing three different columns on the website page.